# Can planning success be checked in the Python MoveGroupCommander?

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The C++ MoveGroup's plan function [returns an error code](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/move_group_interface/move_group_interface_tutorial.html#planning-to-a-pose-goal), but the Python MoveGroupCommander's [plan function](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_commander/html/classmoveit__commander_1_1move__group_1_1MoveGroupCommander.html#a18b673b333ff75be6186619577e75b84) seems to return only the RobotTrajectory. Am I misunderstanding it? What is the best way to check in Python if a motion plan was successful?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304494/can-planning-success-be-checked-in-the-python-movegroupcommander?/) by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2180 on 2018-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By checking if the trajectory contains points, in kinetic/melodic at least:

```
plan = move_group.plan()
if plan.joint_trajectory.points:  # True if trajectory contains points
  move_success = move_group.execute(plan)
else:
  rospy.logerr("Trajectory is empty. Planning was unsuccessful.")
```

Looks like this API might change, and success might be returned via a tuple in the future.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2019-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0